# fprintf only specific lines from text file

Tags: c

Making a program that adds user records to text file; so far so good! Yet I ran into a problem  that I can not figure out on my own.

```
int main()
{

 FILE *fp;
 struct info
 {
    char name[15];
    char surename[15];
    char gender[15];
    char education[15];

 } info;

char c;
int i,j,a;
struct info sem;

beginning:

scanf("%d",&a);

if (a==1)
```

and at this part if user chooses option one 1, program needs to check all the records per person in txt file and printf me every single person information who has bachelors education.

```
{
FILE *fp=fopen("info.txt", "r");
  char tmp[256]={0x0};
  while(fp!=NULL && fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp),fp)!=NULL)

  {

  if(strstr(tmp,"bachelors"))

  printf("test test");

                fprintf(fp, "\n%s %s %s %s %s %s",
                sem.name,
                sem.surname,
                sem.gender,
                sem.education,);


  }
  if(fp!=NULL) fclose(fp);
    goto beginning;
}
```

This code so far detects the word "bachelor" but doesn't want to print out the line where it detected it; any ideas how to solve it? Plus, any suggestions how to make sure program only checks education field and doesn't give me false positive if some one would be named Bachelors?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using `goto`? And sort out the indentation

Comment: have several options at the start what to do with the data, just didnt feel the need to add them!

Comment: That still doesn't explain the `goto`. Why does a loop not suffice in this circumstance?

Comment: Give us a compilable code.

Comment: Give us an example of your info.txt file data and the expected output and the output you are getting now, if you are getting any.

Answer (score 1):

What output do you actually get? You say it doesn't want to print out the correct lines, but does that mean it prints all lines, no lines, some but not others?

Looking at your program, I would hazard a guess that every line is being printed out. You need braces around `if(strstr(tmp,"bachelors"))` if you want more than one statement in the body of the `if`.

EDIT:

In addition to your braces problem, you are attempting to use `fprintf` to print back to `fp`, which was opened in read mode (using the `r` flag). You need to use read/update mode (`r+`) if you want to modify info.txt. However, this is probably not the way you want to do this.

Firstly, you stated you wanted to "printf" the data, which means printing to standard out. If so then you should use `printf` instead of `fprintf`. On the other hand it would seem likely that what you want to do is to read lines from one text file and print data out to another file. In that case you probably want two files.

Even with the above modifications, you will be printing the same data to file each time, since the sem struct is not being updated at all.

Finally, your `fprintf` format string expects six inputs and you only have four (and an erroneous trailing `,`). Why?

Comment: If i have one user with bachelors education, i get "test test", if two "test testtest test", but what I would need is each persons name,surname,gender,education...

Answer (score 1):

printf/fprintf procedures use internal buffers to avoid calling the syscall "write" everytime.
I would say that you should add a '\n' character at the end of your string to actually force flushing the buffers writing the test. Moreover your token "bachelors" has to be in the 256 first characters of your file.
 
Second question depends on how your file is formatted, and you are the only one who knows that.